# Different coordinate system leaflet

Tags: javascript, gis, leaflet

Here is picture of my coordinates shown in the bottom left corner. It gives me coordinates of my mouse position.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT3tO.png

Problem is that it is in global coordinate system (ESPG 4326) but I need it to be in EPSG 3301 (Estonian local coordinate system).

Here is the code of giving coordinates.

```
    L.Control.MousePosition = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'bottomleft',
    separator: ' : ',
    emptyString: 'Unavailable',
    lngFirst: false,
    numDigits: 5,
    lngFormatter: undefined,
    latFormatter: undefined,
    prefix: ""
  },

  onAdd: function (map) {
    this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control-mouseposition');
    L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(this._container);
    map.on('mousemove', this._onMouseMove, this);
    this._container.innerHTML=this.options.emptyString;
    return this._container;
  },

  onRemove: function (map) {
    map.off('mousemove', this._onMouseMove)
  },

  _onMouseMove: function (e) {
    var lng = this.options.lngFormatter ? this.options.lngFormatter(e.latlng.lng) : L.Util.formatNum(e.latlng.lng, this.options.numDigits);
    var lat = this.options.latFormatter ? this.options.latFormatter(e.latlng.lat) : L.Util.formatNum(e.latlng.lat, this.options.numDigits);
    var value = this.options.lngFirst ? lng + this.options.separator + lat : lat + this.options.separator + lng;
    var prefixAndValue = this.options.prefix + ' ' + value;
    this._container.innerHTML = prefixAndValue;
  }

});

L.Map.mergeOptions({
    positionControl: false
});

L.Map.addInitHook(function () {
    if (this.options.positionControl) {
        this.positionControl = new L.Control.MousePosition();
        this.addControl(this.positionControl);
    }
});

L.control.mousePosition = function (options) {
    return new L.Control.MousePosition(options);
};
```

Thanks, 
Kristjan

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert them using the Lambert Conic Conformal (2P) method, which is [well described](http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/g7-2.pdf) but somewhat lengthy to implement, but that didn't stop me. Here's an example implementation that only converts from longitude and latitude to EPSG, not vice versa:

```
function EPSG(lat1, lat2, latF, lonF, EF, NF) {

    this.sqr = function(x) {
        return x*x;
    }

    this.rad = function(x) {
        return Math.PI * x / 180.0;
    }

    lat1 = this.rad(lat1);
    lat2 = this.rad(lat2);
    latF = this.rad(latF);
    lonF = this.rad(lonF);

    this.a = 6378206.400;
    this.e = 0.08227185;
    this.lat1 = lat1;
    this.lat2 = lat2;
    this.latF = latF;
    this.lonF = lonF;
    this.EF = EF;
    this.NF = NF;

    var e = this.e;
    var a = this.a;

    var m1 = Math.cos(lat1) / Math.sqrt(1 - this.sqr(e * Math.sin(lat1)));
    var m2 = Math.cos(lat2) / Math.sqrt(1 - this.sqr(e * Math.sin(lat2)));
    var t1 = Math.tan(0.25 * Math.PI - 0.5 * lat1) /
        Math.pow((1 - e * Math.sin(lat1)) / 
            (1 + e * Math.sin(lat1)), 0.5*e);
    var t2 = Math.tan(0.25 * Math.PI - 0.5 * lat2) /
        Math.pow((1 - e * Math.sin(lat2)) / 
            (1 + e * Math.sin(lat2)), 0.5*e);
    var tF = Math.tan(0.25 * Math.PI - 0.5 * latF) /
        Math.pow((1 - e * Math.sin(latF)) / 
            (1 + e * Math.sin(latF)), 0.5*e);
    var n = (Math.log(m1) - Math.log(m2)) / 
        (Math.log(t1) - Math.log(t2));
    var F = m1 / (n * Math.pow(t1, n));
    var rF = a * F * Math.pow(tF, n);

    this.rF = rF;
    this.n = n;

    this.deg2epsg = function(lon, lat) {
        var e = this.e;
        var a = this.a;

        lon = this.rad(lon);
        lat = this.rad(lat);

        var t = Math.tan(0.25 * Math.PI - 0.5 * lat) /
            Math.pow((1 - e * Math.sin(lat)) /
                (1 + e * Math.sin(lat)), 0.5*e);

        var r = a * F * Math.pow(t, n);
        var theta = n * (lon - lonF);

        var E = this.EF + r * Math.sin(theta);
        var N = this.NF + this.rF - r * Math.cos(theta);

        return [E, N];
    }
}
```

Now you can create an instance of `EPSG` with the [data for EPSG 3301](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3301/) and run its `deg2epsg` method:

```
var epsg3301 = new EPSG(59.33333333333334, 58, 
    57.51755393055556, 24, 500000, 6375000);

var tallinn = epsg3301.deg2epsg(24.7453, 59.4372);

// tallinn[0] == 542293.7844303187
// tallinn[1] == 6589057.033686307
```

Note that most of the data is initialised only once, so that `deg2epsg` should be fairly fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for long reply. Whole thing seems quite complicated and i'm finding trouble using this piece of code.
Basically this code calculates the coordinates manually? How can i get it to be shown in leftbottom corner

Thanks,

Comment: You'll have to create the EPSG projector once; this should probably be a property of your object. The in your `_OnMouse_Move` method, you calculate the easting and northing as shown above. This returns a two-element array. use these values - they are length coordinates - to create a string, then set `this._container.innerHTML` to that string.